# Build android release locally while Google Play manages the app signing key

Tags: android, android-keystore

How do I compile build variants locally while being opted in to Google Play app signing? They created my signing key and I therefore only have an upload key.

I would like to test my staging and release build variants locally, but Android studio requires me to create a signingConfig in my gradle file, with the path to my storeFile the storePassword, keyAlias and keyPassword. When I provide my upload key details and try to build the release or staging version for local testing purposes I just get 'Invalid keystore format'.

My build.gradle files looks something like the following (omitted my details and some buildType variables)

My signing config

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        storeFile file('')
        storePassword ''
        keyAlias 'upload'
        keyPassword ''
    }
}
```

My buildTypes

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
    }
    staging {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I am just using the debug signing configuration locally.